# Override personal access token expire at setting in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, tdd

I m using Personal Access Tokens from travel passport. I have added expiration time for 5 minutes for my application.

In `AuthServiceProvider`

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

I wanted to test the expiry date of a token by overriding the above configuration from `AuthServiceProvider`.

I have tried to override in my test method as follow

```
public function it_should_check_token_expiration()
{
    //override current token expiry
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(2));

    // create fake user
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'test@testing.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('testing'),
        'first_name' => 'testing',
        'last_name'  => 'tester'
    ]);

    //act as auth user
    $this -> actingAs($user, 'api');
    //retrieve token information
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $personalAccessTokenResult = $user -> createToken('MyApp');
    self::assertNotNull($personalAccessTokenResult, 'Unable to create token from given user');
    $minute = $personalAccessTokenResult -> token -> expires_at -> diffInMinutes($now);
    self::assertTrue($minute === 1,'Expired minute not matched');
}
```

It doesn't work. Is there any way, I can use a different setting for my test environment.